# A compact does not imply $f^{-1}(A)$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand the solution to c). I understand $[-1,1]$ is compact by the heine borel, but surely $f^{-1}[-1,1]=[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ hence compact by the heine borel?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The inverse image is all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $\;f^{-1}[-1,1]=\Bbb R\;$ ....

Comment: @DavidMitra Do you mind explaining why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

follows from the fact that for any $x \in \mathbb{R} $

$$ -1 \leq \sin x \leq 1 $$

Hence, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \sin x $, if we let $A = [-1,1]$, then

$$ f^{-1}(A) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 \leq f(x) \leq 1 \} = \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Doesn't an inverse function have to be restricted to make it one to one?

Comment: @lemony9201: $f^{-1}(A)$ is the pre-image of $A$ under $f$ - there is no inverse function involved. Slightly confusing notation.

Comment: @lemony9201 You have to note that $f^{-1}(A)$ is not a number, it is a set which could contain no elements at all or infinitely many.

Comment: @lemony9201 To avoid the confusion, the definition of $f^{-1}$ as preimage was explicitly included in the problem statement!

Answer (score 2):

This is a confusing notation, but $f^{-1}$ sometimes denotes the inverse function, and sometimes denotes the preimage (which is a set-valued function which takes a set and returns a set).

In the case of a preimage we define $f^{-1}(A)=\{x\mid f(x)\in A\}$. Note that it might be empty in some cases. We also write, often, $f^{-1}(x)$ instead of $f^{-1}(\{x\})$, and if $f$ is injective then $\{f^{-1}(x)\}=f^{-1}(\{x\})$ where the left hand side is the inverse function, and the right hand side is the preimage.

Now since all the values of $\sin$ are in the interval $[-1,1]$ it follows that the preimage of $[-1,1]$ is everything, which is not compact. You can also consider a constant function mapping everything to $0$.

So, how can we tell this is preimage and not inverse function? Context. In the context of continuity we already talk about preimage of open/closed set is open/closed. So $f^{-1}(A)$ should strike us as preimage and not inverse; moreover as you wrote if the function is not injective then the inverse is not well-defined, so by writing $f^{-1}$ to a function which is not injective it should imply that we consider the preimage here.

Comment: Dear Asaf,  Your comments about context are sensible and appropriate, but one could also note (as Hagen von Eitzen already did) that in this particular case the definition of $f^{-1}(A)$ was even included as part of the problem!  Cheers,